# What is $ \operatorname{Hom}_{k[x]}(k[x]/\langle x^2 \rangle , k[x]/ \langle x^3 \rangle ) $, where $ k $ is a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Suppose $k$ is a field. I believe that $ \operatorname{Hom}_{k[x]}(k[x]/\langle x^2 \rangle , k[x]/ \langle x^3 \rangle ) = 0$, since by the universal property for quotients, homomorphisms in $ \operatorname{Hom}_{k[x]}(k[x]/\langle x^2 \rangle , k[x]/ \langle x^3 \rangle )  $ are characterised by

$$ \phi \colon k[x] \to k[x]/\langle x^3 \rangle \qquad \phi(\langle x^2\rangle)=0.$$

This means $ \phi(x^2) = 0 $ so $ x^2 \phi(1) = 0 $ and $ \phi(1) = 0 $. Therefore, $\phi(p(x)) = 0$ for any polynomial $ p(x) \in k[x] $.

But it seems we haven't really used $ k[x]/\langle x^3 \rangle $ at all, so $ \operatorname{Hom}_{k[x]}(k[x]/\langle x^2 \rangle , k[x]/ \langle x^n \rangle )  = 0$ for any $ n > 2 $?

How about $ \operatorname{Hom}_{k[x]}(k[x]/\langle x^m\rangle, k[x]/\langle x^n\rangle)$, for integers $ m, n$, is this still $0$?

Comment: It's not entirely justified to go from $\phi(x^2) = 0$ to $x^2 \phi(1) = 0$, since the $x$ on either side could differ... But, the map sending $x \mapsto x^3$ works. For instance if $f(x) = x + 1$ then $\phi(f(x)) = x^3 + 1$, and if $f(x) = x^2$ then $\phi(f(x)) = (x^3)^2 = x^6 = 0$.

Comment: Why would $x^2\phi(1)=0$ imply $\phi(1)=0$?

Comment: the question as written is about morphisms of $k[x]$ modules. But you seem to be considering morphisms of rings.

Answer (score 1):

This is a correction and replacement of my original response, which ignored the request for homomorphisms from $k[x]/\langle x^2\rangle$ to $k[x]/\langle x^3\rangle$ *as $k[x]$-modules*. I thank @Max for pointing out my error.

It helps to look at the parallel question of the homomorphisms between the $\Bbb Z$-modules $\Bbb Z/p^2\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Z/p^3\Bbb Z$. Of course there is a nontrivial map, $n\mapsto pn$. In the same way, we have $a+bx\mapsto ax+bx^2$, multiplication by $x$, as a nontrivial $k[x]$-homomorphism from $k[x]/\langle x^2\rangle$ to $k[x]/\langle x^3\rangle$.

Comment: The question is about $k[x]$-module morphisms

Comment: Unending thanks, @Max, for pointing out the error in my original post.